# Schematic diagram probe question

Tags: diagram, probe

I am not sure whether to call it a probe on my schematic diagram or is it something else.

I have ATmega328P checking its two digital pins whether both have been connected to the ground. When floating, these pins are HIGH. The only time that it becomes LOW is when it senses the ground through a detachable conductive material that has 3 terminals for the two digital pins and the ground.

Is it considered a probe? What should I call it in my schematic diagram?

Comment: 'detachable conductive material that has 3 terminals'  .... i would say that is a wire harness .... or just a wire with 3 connectors

Comment: @jsotola, how should I illustrate it as a symbol in the schematic diagram (conductive material with 3 terminals)?

Comment: you don't usually put harnesses in a schematic diagram .... you include the connectors in the schematic diagram ..... harnesses are more of a wiring diagram item